# Find shortest path that visits all nodes in a given set of nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Suppose I have a graph $G$ and a set of target nodes $S = \{A_1, ..., A_n\}$. I'm attempting to find the shortest path that visits each target node, in order, without visiting the same node twice.

For example, consider the following:

[image: example]

I have attempted to solve this by first performing a breadth-first search to find the shortest path from A to B, then from B to C, and so on, taking care to exclude any paths already found at each iteration.

This greedy solution works for most inputs, but in some case it will fail to find a solution, as the shortest path between two target nodes may end up blocking the complete path.

Aside from a brute-force approach, is it possible to find the shortest path that visits all of the target nodes, and is guaranteed to find such a path if one exists? Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: In addition to what @D.W. said, I would suggest [Lin-Kernighan heuristic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin–Kernighan_heuristic)

Comment: The solution you suggest isn't optimal. A shorter solution is to make the A-B path go north of D, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d68Cp.gif). This gives cost 22, whereas your solution has cost 24.

Comment: @D.W. I'm not sure TSP algorithms will be much use: in this situation, the order of the cities is fixed and the difficulty is that we might need to pick a suboptimal route between one pair of cities to save space later on.

Comment: So a path is going from grid point to grid point, and the same grid point must not be used twice?

Comment: gnasher729's question is important. Knowing the points lie on a grid and the edges are the grid neighborhood relation allows more efficient solutions.

Comment: The problem of determining whether a feasible solution exists can be seen as a special case of [zig-zag numberlink](https://www.isnphard.com/i/zig-zag-numberlink/) (some technical care is needed but you can essentially "zoom out" your grid and duplicate each target node), which is known to be NP-hard. I suspect that the problem remains hard.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a more general problem [a couple days ago](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96746/finding-paths-with-minimum-intersections/96748#96748). You simply want the destination pairs to be (a, b), (b, c), (c,d ),etc.

The gist is to translate the problem into a minimum-cost integer multi-commodity flow problem with a maximum capacity of $1$ per node, and one commodity between each pair of destinations.

Comment: You reduce this problem to minimum-cost integer multi-commodity flow problem, which is not sufficient to show this problem is NP-complete.

Comment: @xskxzr Right. I removed that claim.